# Whats wrong in my regex pattern?

Tags: c#, regex

I'm wrote a pattern

```
string pattern2 = @"(?[<ports>\w+,*]*)";
```

This pattern should help parse string of next format

```
[port1, port2_4][portN_][port,port2,port5,p0_p1]
```

After parsing I'm want to have array of strings:

```
1. port1, port2_4
2. portN_
3. port, port2,port5,p0_p1
```

Comment: What question mark in the beginning means?

Comment: As I'm understood this means start of the group

Comment: Could you wrote some more constructive comments, please? If you know how to change my pattern for my task, please write your kind of pattern

Comment: I suggest getting Expresso  ( its free ) and it will help with creating C# regex

Comment: @pipsik: I'm used to thinking people come here to learn. But sometimes (like now) they for a free fish. Do you realize that you'll learn nothing if you just copy-paste from other people answers?

Comment: @zerkms I'm new in regex and I'm ask question. Whats a problem? Actually, I'm not a ask "Could you write a code for me?". I'm ask whats wrong in my pattern for my task!

Comment: @pipsik: do you understand now what was wrong with the original regex? I mean, can you just close this page and write a correct regular expression from the scratch?

Comment: @zerkms I'm will try it now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this will work...

```
(?<=\[)(?<ports>.*?)(?=\])
```

- `(?<=\[)`  prefix of `[` but dont include in match
- `(?<ports>.*?)` named capture "ports" match anything non greedy ( as little as
  possible)
- `(?=\])` suffix of `]` but don't include it in the match

code :-

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"(?<=\[)(?<ports>.*?)(?=\])");
var m = regex.Matches("[port1, port2_4][portN_][port,port2,port5,p0_p1]");
foreach (var p in m)
{
    Console.WriteLine(p);
}
```

output :

```
port1, port2_4
portN_
port,port2,port5,p0_p1
```

Comment: portNames always inside a brackets "[]". Port names may be separated by ",". Please, check my example at my main post

Comment: No. The content of one couple of [] should be one element of string array

Comment: Deleted that comment whilst you were posting, I too was tricked by the formatting of the question.